# how to stop redirection of parent href tag when clicked on child div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

i have the following structure

Code

```
 <a href="blah.html" class="re-direct">
    <div class="1div"></div>
    <div class="2div">
       <div class="click" data-id="text">click</div>
    </div>
 </a>
 <script>
  $(document).on('click',".click",function(){ alert($(this).data('id')) })
 </script>
```

the above code works fine but it redirects to the page blah.html how do i stop it from redirecting ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the click event up the DOM to the `a` element, and also prevent the default behaviour of the link:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).data('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="blah.html" class="re-direct">
  <div class="1div"></div>
  <div class="2div">
    <div class="click" data-id="text">click</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Yup now it works but will return false work the same?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are there any uses of preventDefault() outside of links?

Comment: @Mr.coder Yes, although returning false kills everything returned by the function, which may not be intended behaviour. In this case it should be fine though.

Comment: @Claudiu yes. For example, it can be used on the `submit` event to stop the form submission.