# React-router Link component prevent default for child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to place an `onClick` handler on `Link` child. The problem is it is not firing because of `Link's` `transition` method. Is there any `preventDefault` or so? Here's the example in jquery world 
[how to stop redirection of parent href tag when clicked on child div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726358/how-to-stop-redirection-of-parent-href-tag-when-clicked-on-child-div)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the `onClick` docs:

> A custom handler for the click event. Works just like a handler on an `a` tag - calling `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the transition from firing, while `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling.

So you should just be able to use `e.preventDefault`

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onclicke